# Experiencing fade lag when element animates for the first time

Tags: performance, animation, svg, fade, lag

I have some custom buttons that control when to fade in an element (done in Jquery). For the most part, the functionality is how I'd expect it. The only problem is that when I press any of the buttons for the first time there is a delay in the animation (sometimes seeming to skip it entirely). I suspect this has to do with the initial loading of the content and the subsequent caching after the initial load.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
$('.content').hide();
$('.button').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
        if (!state.isExpanded){
            $('.button').animate({height: '5vw', width: '5%'}, 500);
            $('#button-container').animate({height: '100%', width: '100%'}, 500);
            showSection($(this), 1000);
 ...
 ...
```

showSection:

```
    function showSection(elem, duration) {
    var elemID = $(elem).attr('id');
    console.log(elemID);
    switch(elemID){
        case 'person-icon':
        $(aboutMeSection.ID).find('.content').fadeIn(duration);
        break;
    ...
    ...
```

Worth noting that I'm trying to load in multiple custom SVG images created in illustrator the largest single object being 2.2 mB. This is my first time creating a website so it's not apparent to me what reasonable sizes are media elements. Might this be too large?

Comment: Replace with a smaller image to test. 2.2 MB is indeed too large, specially for a vector file.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. The SVG image was too complex to optimize so I just created a PNG version of it instead (don't know why I insisted on it being SVG in the first place). Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the SVG image I was using was too large. Just so this question isn't a complete waste to anyone that has a similar problem.

- Consider whether the image you're using needs to be an SVG. Being a noobie I got caught up in its recent popularity and saved every image I created as an SVG when a PNG would do just fine.
- A good article on SVG optimization I was reading before figured out what to do:

  [Optimizing SVGs for Web Use](https://medium.com/larsenwork-andreas-larsen/optimising-svgs-for-web-use-part-1-67e8f2d4035#.53a5nvbfq)